# How to declare a dynamic ng-model? angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, controller, angular-ngmodel

I was trying to make dynamic input. is it possible to have dynamic ng-model by index?

[See scrnsht here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvpdJ.png)

supposedly barcode ng-model from above should be set into ng-model="barcode_0" and ng-model="barcode_1"

I have tried this code, but it doesnt work

```js
//controller
console.log($scope['Barcode_' + index])
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" ng-model="Barcode_[$index]" class="form-control" placeholder="Stock ID" >
```

Anyone? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need a little change in the code.

`Barcode_[$index]` is an element of the array `Barcode_`. You just need to `initialize` this array in the `controller`, and then you can use`$scope.Barcode_[0]` and `$scope.Barcode_[1]` in your `controller` to access the variables.

Leave the html code as it is, and Do this is your controller:

```
$scope.Barcode_ = [];//initializing the array
```

You can access the variables like this in this controller:

```
console.log($scope.Barcode_[0]);//prints first one
console.log($scope.Barcode_[1]);//prints second one
```

Comment: or is it possible to do this? ng-model="Barcode_{{$index}}" ??
or anything with the same idea creating auto/dynamic ng-model declaration

Comment: you cant just do that, it wont concatenate `$index` to `Barcode_` for creating `dynamic ng-model`. For that you will have to use it as an `array`. My code also creates dynamic `ng-model`, but they are a part of the array Barcode_, not separate variable as Barcode_0 and Barcode_1. Just try the workaround that i suggested, and you would be good to go.